# How can I save and show nested model's radio button parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 models, survey - question - answer, each has_many/belongs_to relation.

This is input form.

```
<ol>
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= simple_fields_for "questions[#{question.id}]" do |builder| %>
        <li>
          <%= builder.input :answer, :collection => question.answers, :as => :radio_buttons,
               :label_method => :content, :value_method => :id, :label => question.content %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

I realized that radio_buttons works well from the log.

```
  Parameters: {"survey_id"=>"23", "commit"=>"Submit Exam", "questions"=>{"8"=>{"answer"=>"28"}, "7"=>{"answer"=>"24"}, "6"=>{"answer"=>"21"}}, "authenticity_token"=>"m/16DAjhDrEH3/8fzJLDeiqi/d+VkZJiOeqK5TuLpSw=", "utf8"=>"✓"}
```

I can get each value in the create method in the controller like this. so far so good.

```
@checked_answers = params[:questions]
```

I want to show user's input in show view. However I can't use @checked_answers value in show method. I think I have to save it in DB, maybe I have to create another column in the DB tables for saving @checked_answers. But that is not a simple data!(like string or integer ...) Are there any good way to avoid saving data in DB? If I can use that params directly in the show view, all problem can be solved!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, You did this:

```
@checked_answers = params[:questions]
```

Now you have this in `@checked_answers`:

```
{"8"=>{"answer"=>"28"}, "7"=>{"answer"=>"24"}, "6"=>{"answer"=>"21"}}
```

Do this in your view :

```
@checked_answers.each_with_index do |ques, answer|
   "Question No #{ques}"

   "Correct Answer #{answer}"
```

Or if these are the ids of questions & answers, you can find them in you database as well.

Thanks

Comment: params that I've showed were from create(POST) action, I want to use them in show(GET) action. but params in show(GET) are different. What I want to save params and use in show action. Can anybody help?